# scss require in rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

In rails "and scss" website Im trying to add

```
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
```

in my

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
```

but Im getting an error

```
Invalid CSS after " *": expected "{", was "= require boots..."
```

So what a *= require?

[Documentation](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your line with

`/*
*= require bootstrap-datepicker3
*/`